# Remove zero in a column

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table with a column of type `nvarchar(max)`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (Col1 nvarchar(max))

INSERT table1 values('A001')
INSERT table1 values('A005')
INSERT table1 values('A021')
INSERT table1 values('A002')
INSERT table1 values('A015')
INSERT table1 values('A151')
```

This is the output from my select query

```
A001
A002
A005
A015
A021
A151
```

I want to remove zeroes after `A` to get this output:

```
A1
A2
A5
A15
A21
A151
```

Comment: Remove the first character and then leading zeroes

Comment: What if the data is like this `A150` will you remove the zero here

Comment: @NoDisplayName: OP obviously wants to remove leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try Like this,,,

```
Select LEFT(Col1, 1)+ Cast(CAST(Replace(Col1,'A','') as Int) as nvarchar(Max)) as Col1 from Table1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b976b/4)

Comment: What if a row has `B013`

Comment: I have a string A001, A011, A002, A14, A158, A010 stored in a temp variable in a procedure and want this output A1, A11, A2, A14, A158, A10.

Answer (score 0):

```
select left(Col1,1)+ltrim(convert(int,substring(Col1,2,99)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using Replace()

Select REPLACE(Col1,'0','') as Col1 from Table1;